# ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg' django

Tags: django, postgresql, server, psycopg2, google-search-console

My site was working well in cpanel. when i add google search console for seo, after one day I am seeing such error.
[image: image description here]

Passenger.log file
[image: image description here]

My os is Windows. Please help guys. I would be very grateful.

I installed psycopg2-binary as psycopg2 didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It is as follows:
Because of server I needed to decrease the django version. Then it again started working after changing django version.